# Puxar somente itens que forem do usuário

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json, query

Fala pessoal, tenho 1 banco e dados com 2 tabelas até agora a primeira tabela é responsavel por cadastrar os usuario com o nome "usuarios", a outra tabela é onde quero cadastrar os eventos no Full_calendar com JS, meu código atual consigo puxar tudo que está lá, porém gostaria de aparecer os eventos indiduais de cada usuarios.

Segue meu código de busca em PHP:

```
<?php

include 'conexao.php';

$query_events = "SELECT id, title, color, start, end, usuario FROM events";


$resultado_events = $conn->prepare($query_events);
$resultado_events->execute();

$eventos = [];

while($row_events = $resultado_events->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row_events['id'];
    $title = $row_events['title'];
    $color = $row_events['color'];
    $start = $row_events['start'];
    $end = $row_events['end'];
    
    $eventos[] = [
        'id' => $id, 
        'title' => $title, 
        'color' => $color, 
        'start' => $start, 
        'end' => $end, 
        ];
}

echo json_encode($eventos);


?>
```

e as informações das tabelas:

events = id, title, color, start, end, usuario

usuarios = id, nome, usuario, email, senha

gostaria de mostrar no calendário só o que é de cada usuário quando ele logar, o sistema de login já está funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar a cláusula `WHERE` na sua query de consulta de eventos para filtrar pelo usuário autenticado.

Supondo que seu usuário está na `$_SESSION` no índice usuario, e o valor armazenado nesta variável seja apenas o seu id, e também que a coluna `usuario` na tabela `events` é a chave estrangeira de usuario; adicione a seguinte linha para concatenar o filtro:

```
$query_events = "SELECT id, title, color, start, end, usuario FROM events ";
$query_events .= " WHERE usuario = '".$_SESSION['usuario']."'";
```

O restante de seu código aparentemente não precisará de mais alterações.

### Rápida explicação da cláusula

A cláusula `WHERE` é lida `QUANDO`, então a leitura da SQL seria algo próximo de: "SELECIONE id, title, color, start, end, usuario DA TABELA events QUANDO usuario = valor"

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, porém não esta buscando, não estou conseguindo criar $_SESSION['usuario'] ao logar, tenho esse código:

Comment: acho que vou filtrar pelo ID, mas queria pelo usuario

Comment: se você colocar o código que grava o usuário autenticado na sessão me ajuda a te ajudar, de início estou fazendo suposições, quando disse usuário me referi a qualquer valor q vc esteja usando como chave primária e estrangeira. Se está usando o nome do usuário, basta fazer os ajustes no código de exemplo